# How do I get the Storyboard name?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uistoryboard

Im creating a new design to my app so I have created a new story board. I need to support the older design for now, but I am designing the upcoming one on the fly. I am reusing some classes and ViewControllers. Is there a way to check the storyboard name in classes? For Example, if 'main' storyboard have the normal left bar button item, however if 'newDesign' do 'x'?

I cant find a way to get the 'UIStoryboard' name?

For example in pseudocode:

```
if(self.storyboard.name isEqualToString: @"Main"){


}else{

}
```

Comment: check my answer i have edited..

Comment: DevC check another approach that i suggested to my answer.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: Rather than checking which storyboard is being used, check if the stuff is available in the current storyboard or not. Or another solution, if you are setting storyboards from the appdelegate, then user the same exact condition.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
UIStoryboard * storyboard1 = self.storyboard;
NSString *name=[storyboard1 valueForKey:@"name"];

NSLog(@"%@",name);
```

Another approach is to **check the restoration ID** of the view controllers. How about that?

Comment: Isnt [storyboard1 valueForKey:..] from a private API?

Comment: I did not check that. I am looking on it right now.